# Is there a notion of "maximally intransitive" relation, or "maximally nonassociative" operator?

Tags: relations, associativity

Transitivity on relations $R\subseteq X\times X$ and associativity on binary operators $+:X\times X \to X$ are defined as:

$$\forall x,y,z, \quad xRy\land yRz\to xRz$$

$$\forall x,y,z, \quad (x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$$

I am interested whether there is **some** notion of a "most non-transitive" relation or "most non-associative" operator. Some seem to be more intransitive or more nonassociative than others.

If we define the formulas $T_R(t):xRy\land yRz\to xRz$ for $t=(x,y,z)$ and $A_+(t):(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$, then it would be tempting to just say that the minimally transitive relation is the one for which this doesnt satisfy for any $t\in X^3$, but there clearly isnt such a relation. Similar for associativity.

Is there **some** way that we can formalize the notion of "minimal" transitivity/associativity?

Comment: If you have a way to define [associators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associator), you can look at how much of your structure they (in some appropriate sense) generate.

Comment: For relations, you have [antitransitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitivity#Antitransitivity)

Comment: The Hasse diagram of a finite partial order might be considered minimally transitive.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to generalize the notion of **center** $Z(X)$ of a group *( or ring, or etc.)* $X$ - namely, the set of elements which **commute with everything**. Of course, since associativity takes three elements into account, this is a bit stranger; I suspect that the right thing to look at, given a binary function $*$, is the set $$A(X)=\{b: \forall a,c[(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)]\}.$$ Note that $A(X)$ is itself closed under $*$ (this is easy to check) and is itself completely associative, which does suggest that this isn't too terrible a notion.

"Minimal associativity" then could mean that $A(X)$ is as small as possible, in whatever context we're considering. E.g. in an arbitrary magma this would mean $A(X)=\emptyset$; if we commit ourselves to having an identity element $e$, then $A(X)$ must contain it (since $(a*e)*c=a*c=a*(e*c)$) but could in principle consist of *just* the identity.

Unfortunately, while smallness of *center* is often important, I'm not aware of any situations where $A(X)$ being "small" is actually interesting. But then I'm not familiar with non-associative algebraic structures in general.

Answer (score 0):

Let S be a set with at least 3 points.
T = SxS is a transitive relation.
For distinct a,b, let R = T - {(a,b)}.
R is not transitive because there is a point c
with aRc and cRb but without aRb.
Thus R is maximally intransitive.

Comment: the empty relation would be "maximally intransitive" under your definition, even though it  is transitive. Also, it is not uniquely defined. assume that $xRy$ hold for all $x,y\in \tilde X$ for some subset $\tilde X$. There are multiple relations satisfying the definition that are not isomorphic. Maybe we cannot get around that but it's not obvious to me.

Comment: @user56834.  See edit.  Maximal things usually are not unique.

Comment: but this notion is not really sensible. like I said, there are relations that are "transitive" but "maximally intransitive" according to this definition. moreover, a "maximally intransitive" relation $R$ can be made more intransitive (in an intuitive sense), by **adding** elements to $R$.

Comment: @user56834. See revision.

Comment: If $R$ is the empty relation, $T$ is transitive. If $R$ is the relation only containing $(a,b)$, $T$ is also transitive. If $R$ is a massive relation with lots of connections, removing only $(a,b)$ doesn’t make it “maximally intransitive” in any meaningful sense.

Comment: @user56834.  R cannot be empty because T has at least 9 elements.  Indeed, the notion of maximally intransitive is not particularly meaningful.  How could there any use for it?

Comment: Sorry I misread your definition of $T$. Anyway, I'm gonna let this discussion go.